# How do i fix invalid operands of type double in C++?

Tags: c++

Trying to do a Lab for school, but i keep getting this same error over and over again, and I am not sure what exactly it means.

First, here is my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const double PI = acos(-1); // arccos(-1) produces the value pi
const double SEC_IN_DAY = 86400;
const double MU = 1.3274745e20;
const double R_EARTH = 1.496e11;

double ConvertSecondsToDays(double seconds){
   return seconds / SEC_IN_DAY;
}

double CubedSum(double v1, double v2){
   return pow(v1,v2);
}

double DirectTime (double rDestination){
    return 2.0 * sqrt(fabs(rDestination - 1.496e11) / 10) / 86400.0;
    
}

double HohmannTime(double r1, double r2){
   return PI * sqrt((CubedSum)/ 8.0 * MU);
}


int main() {


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is at line 25, where it give me the following error:

```
 "main.cpp: In function ‘double HohmannTime(double, double)’:
main.cpp:25:31: error: invalid operands of types ‘double(double, double)’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator/’
   25 |    return PI * sqrt((CubedSum)/ 8.0 * MU);
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~
      |                      |          |
      |                      |          double
      |                      double(double, double)
```

I have looked up what this error means, but am not 100% sure what to do on fixing it.

Comment: `CubedSum` is not a `double`, it is a function that accepts two `double`s as arguments and returns a `double`. Did you mean something like `CubedSum(r1, r2)`?

Comment: what that is supposed to do is use the pow function to add the two numbers and take the cubed root.  

Here is what is says in my assingment:

"Write a function with the following definition:

    double CubedSum(double v1, double v2)
that adds the two numbers passed in and returns the cube of that sum (i.e. (v1+v2)3 ). You may want to include the cmath library and use the pow() function which has the following definition: double pow (double base, double power) and computes basepower and returns the result. For example, if you called pow(10,3) it would compute 103 and return 1000."

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to use `const double PI = acos(-1)` when C++ provides [`std::numbers::pi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants)

Comment: Thank you brian!  I will remember that for the future, however in this case that is code they gave me at the start and i was told not to edit, so it wasnt of my doing.  

But thank you for the information!

Comment: Note that your implementation of `CubedSum` is incorrect. `CubedSum(1, 1)` should be `(1 + 1)^3 = 2^3 = 8`, but your function will return `pow(1, 1) = 1` without performing either a sum or a cubing operation.

Comment: Thank you Nathan!  I tried that earlier, however, when i do `return (v1 + v2)^3.0`

It gives me that same invald operands error.

Comment: Well, that's because `^` doesn't mean exponentiation in C++. How would you use the `pow` function to represent `(v1 + v2)^3.0`?

Comment: If i may ask, why am i getting so many downvotes on my question?  Im rather new to this so im confused as to why people are downvoting it.

Also, thanks for your help Nathan!  I got the `CubedSum` funciton working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CubedSum` is a function. So it seems you need to write

```
double HohmannTime(double r1, double r2){
   return PI * sqrt((CubedSum( r1, r2 )/ 8.0 * MU);
}
```

instead of

```
double HohmannTime(double r1, double r2){
   return PI * sqrt((CubedSum)/ 8.0 * MU);
}
```

where in this statement

```
return PI * sqrt((CubedSum)/ 8.0 * MU);
```

there is used the function pointer (due to implicit conversion of the function to a pointer) instead of the result of a function call.

Comment: Thank you a ton Vlad!! that seemed to fix that issue, however, now I am having that same issue on line 16 which i changed to be :

`double CubedSum(double v1, double v2){
   return (v1 + v2)^3.0;`

If you can, would you explain what the error i described in my question is?

Comment: @Gunslinger56 `^` is bitwise XOR, not power. Do `(v1 + v2)*(v1 + v2)*(v1 + v2)` instead